# Merging tracks in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

(Using Neo4j 3.x and neo4j.v1 Python driver)

I have two tracks T1 and T2 to the same target. Somewhere before reaching the target, the two tracks meet at node X and become one until the target is reached.

    `Track T1:    T----------X-----------A
    Track T2:               '-----Q`

[image: Model I would like to have: two tracks join at the first common trackpoint]

I use the following Cypher query to generate each one of the tracks:

    `UNWIND {coords} AS coordinates 
    UNWIND {pax} AS pax
    CREATE (n:Node)
    SET n = coordinates
    SET n.pax = pax
    RETURN n`

using the parameter list, e.g. {'pax': 'A', 'coords': [{'id': 0, 'lon': '8.553095', 'lat': '47.373146'}, etc.]}
and then link the nodes using the id only for the purpose of keeping the sequence of the trackpoints:

    `UNWIND {pax} AS pax
    MATCH (n:Node {pax: pax})
    WITH n
    ORDER BY n.id
    WITH COLLECT(n) AS nodes
    UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(nodes) - 2) AS idx
    WITH nodes[idx] AS n1, nodes[idx+1] AS n2
    MERGE (n1)-[:NEXT]->(n2)`

From the (unknown) point X (CS1 in the picture above) on, both tracks have identical trackpoints. I can match those using:

    `MATCH (n:Node), (m:Node) 
    WHERE m <> n AND n.id < m.id AND n.lat = m.lat AND n.lon = m.lon 
    MERGE (n)-[:IS]->(m)`

with lat, lon being the (identical) coordinates. This is just my clumsy way to determine the first joint trackpoint. What I really need is to have one (linked) track from point X onward with the pax property updated, e.g. as ['A', 'B']

**Question 1** (generalized):
How can I merge two nodes with a relationship into one node with an updated property? C3 and S3 merge into a new node CS3.
[image: The clumsy model I currently have: two tracks have their joint trackpoints joined by means of a relationship]

**Question 2**:
How can I do this if I have two linked lists with a set of pairwise identical properties?

    `(Ax)-[:NEXT]->        (A1)-[:NEXT]->(A2)-[:NEXT]->(A3)
    (Ax)-[:NEXT]->        (B1)-[:NEXT]->(B2)-[:NEXT]->(B3)
    where Ax.x <> Bx.x but A1.x = B1.X and A2.x = B2.x etc.`

Thank you all for your hints and helpful ideas.

Comment: There is no way to merge two nodes in Neo4j.
You would need to create a new node with the properties of both nodes, connect the previous and next in the linked list (basically inserting an element in the middle of a linked list) and then delete the old nodes. Or you could pick one linked list over the other and copy the node properties to it before deleting the other one.

Comment: Thank you. I know you can't merge nodes. What I try to avoid is FOREACH and loop through every single one of the "identical" nodes. I would favor keeping one of the linked lists and copy the properties of the one to delete into the first one, updating the joining NEXT relationship, then deleting the second linked list. Is there a "bulk" query that would do this without explicitly looping through all nodes using FOREACH?